# Export NASA USDA HSL SMAP soil moisture TIFF from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth, image, download

I am trying to download soil moisture data from Google Earth Engine using the following code:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA_USDA/HSL/SMAP_soil_moisture')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2017-04-01', '2017-04-30'));
var soilMoisture = dataset.select('ssm');


// Create a geometry representing an export region.
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-76.5060023341, 3.67837906194, -75.9877703115, 3.53457543477]);

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: dataset.select('ssm'),
  description: 'soilMoisture',
  scale: 250,
  folder: 'google_earth',
  region: geometry,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
})
```

I am using the information of the data set from here
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NASA_USDA_HSL_SMAP_soil_moisture

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input': Invalid type. Expected type: Image<unknown bands>. Actual type: ImageCollection.
```

I am not sure the cause behind the error because I am selecting the band ssm.

Any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`Export.image` only accepts a single image. You have provided an image *collection*, which contains multiple images over time.

If you want to get the most recent data available at each point, as `Map.addLayer(dataset)` would do, then `.mosaic()` it:

```js
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: dataset.select('ssm').mosaic(),
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you, it works adding the part of mosaic, but I have one question, what do you mean by "to get the most recent data available"? I am not sure which tiff I am downloading, Am I downloading only the one for the day '2017-04-30' adding the part of mosaic?

Comment: @Sss Mosaicing means that for each pixel of the viewed or exported area, Earth Engine will choose the last (most recent) image in the collection that covers that area. This composite image is not identical to any of the images in the collection, unless the last image covers the entire `region:` you specified.

Comment: and could you tell me how to adapt this part of the code ```.filter(ee.Filter.date('2017-04-01', '2017-04-30')``` to only download the image for one specific day? I want to avoid the operation of the mosaic, and only get the soil moisture for one day

Comment: @Sss If you use `.first()` instead of `.mosaic()` you'll get the earliest image in the collection, so if there's daily images and you set the filter to cover only one day then you'll get the day's image.